# Output by number in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

What is the right syntax of this? I want to output not every result, but I want to output by number. For example from 1 to 20 of results etc. Or only 1st,3rd and 5th numbers of results. Can I make an array of the results?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
  $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
  $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];

// I want to output something like the following in the for loop:
  echo $target_path[0],
  echo $target_path[5],
  echo $target_path[3],
}
```

Comment: do you mean that you only want to print at an odd index?

Comment: Thats right. I need the index of this loop.

Comment: well, a number is even if it is divisible by 2, so a number will be odd if it is not divisible by 2. Using this you can add an if statement in the body of your for loop - something like `if($i % 2 != 0) { //then this is an odd index }`

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output for that sample.

Comment: Some clarification is needed. In your description, you mention you want 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. However in your example code you show echoing index `0`, `3`, and `5`. Which is actually the 1st, 4th, and 6th element in the array. If you want the 1st, 3rd, and 5th elements, you're looking for echoing every EVEN index.

Comment: Does it output the first result? if($i = 0){echo $target_path;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Modulo Arithmetic Operators you can echo based on the index.

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

```
if(($i % 2) == 1)  //odd
}
```

So this should work:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
  $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
  $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
  if(($i % 2) == 1)
      echo $target_path;
  }
}
```

Comment: So this outputs the first result? if($i = 0){echo $target_path;}

Comment: It should be `if ($i == 0){ echo $target_path }'`. If you want to compare values, use `==`. If you want to make sure the type and value match use `===`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 3):

For first 20:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']) && $i < 20; $i++) {
    // ...
}
```

For first, third, fifth, etc. elements:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i += 2) {
    // ...
}
```

Or generally for any condition:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    if(/* condition */) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or this form prevents unnecessary indentation:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    if(/* !condition */) {
        continue;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `+=` in the increment. Too many people seem to forget/not know you can increment by any amount you'd like.

Comment: Does this output the first result? if($i = 0){echo $target_path;}

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach instead for and after you put conditions to get out what index you want.

```
//If you need an array of results
$results = [];
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $index => $file) {
  $ext = explode('.', basename($file))
  $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];

    //here you can put your conditions
    //example:
    //if you need only index < 20  
    if($index < 20){

     //if yo need only odd index: (0,2,4,6 ...)
      if ($index % 2 == 1) {

        //if you need to save only file 
        $results[] = $file;

        //if you need to save only index
        $results[] = $index;

        //if you need both (index and file)
        $results[] = [$index,$file];

        //same for your variable $target_path
        //Don't forget: If you use one of above examples you need to comment the others what you don't need.

      }else{
        //here you can do idem as above but for even index (1,3,5 ... etc)
      }
    }

}
```